# SVN Causing Errors with Make

Tags: svn, makefile, tortoisesvn, mingw32

I have run into an issue where I am able to build a c++ hello world in a folder on my desktop but not able to build the same program inside the working copy of an SVN repository.

**Here are the details:**
Here is what I am running in the windows terminal to build my hello world:

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.mak
```

When I run this line in my 'non-SVN directory', helloWorld.exe builds successfully and I am able to run it. When I run this line in my SVN working copy I get the following error: `mingw32-make: *** INTERNAL: readdir: Invalid argument.  Stop.`

My program is:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

My makefile is:

```
all:
g++ helloWorld.cpp -o helloWorld
```

**Another clue might be...**

Though I'm not currently editing or building in Visual Studio, it also might be worth noting that I am unable to create Visual Studio projects in the working copy directory. I get the following error:
[image: Visual Studio Error]
 (and yes, I am able to create projects in other locations successfully)

**Some supplementary information:**

- I'm on Windows 10
- I have TortoiseSVN 1.7.12 - 64 bit
- Subversion 1.7.9
- GNU Make 3.82.90
- Visual Studio 2015 Professional

My directory structure is:

```
+-- Desktop
|    +-- filterSim2_local         (working copy directory)
|    |    +-- .svn
|    |    +-- make test           (this one doesn't work)
|    |    |    +-- helloWorld.cpp
|    |    |    +-- Makefile.mak
|    +-- make test                (and this one does work)
|    |    +-- helloWorld.cpp
|    |    +-- Makefile.mak
```

Any help or answers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a definitive answer, I was able to solve my problem by checking out a new working copy. Both of my problems with make and VS have been solved. I haven't confirmed this, but I suspect it has to do with a refreshed .svn folder.